# Routing requests to services based on URI prefix in Istio VS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, contextpath

This is what I want to achieve:
Route traffic to a service based on the URI prefix

Problem I'm facing:
Unable to segregate the prefix from the context path

Explanation:

I want to route traffic to a services based on the prefix.
Say, */**dev**/service/context/path/*  and */**test**/service/context/path/* .
But I'm not able to do so without changing the context path of the application itself.

Is there a way I can segregate the prefix part of URI from the context path of application?

This is what my VS looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: servicea
  namespace: dev
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - dev-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8080
        host: servicea
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. I guess you can just add a rewrite rule like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: servicea
  namespace: dev
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - dev-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev
    rewrite:
       uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8080
        host: servicea
```

By this your traffic for `/dev/service/context/path/` becomes `/service/context/path/`.